# Class template overload based on presense of non-type parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a templated class that works as such:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t maxSize>
class Foo
{
    std::array<T, maxSize> arr; 
};
```

I'd like to make an overload where you can choose to only pass T and instead get a vector as the underlying container:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    std::vector<T> arr; 
};
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Would you be ok with making `maxSize` an `int`, instead of `size_t`?

Comment: Yup, that would be fine.

Comment: Would you be ok with a single class that contains the appropriate member based on whether the second template parameter is specified?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have `Foo<T,0>` use `vector` instead of `array`? There is not a lot of use for a zero-length array, but I would not assume "no use" unless you agree. A more general question: is there any value for `maxSize` that reasonably can be co-opted to mean "use a vector" instead of specifying an array size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a parameter pack for the size, and specialize on 1 argument or 0 arguments:

First, provide a default that fails to compile

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
class Foo {
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "too many sizes");
};
```

Then, partially specialize for one or zero arguments:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t maxSize>
class Foo<T, maxSize> {
public:
    std::array<T, maxSize> arr;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T>
{
public:
    std::vector<T> arr;  
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5bW9c7

Comment: The plus of this is that later when you need a two dimensional array it just works.

Comment: Very nice. You can simplify this further by simply not defining the primary. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qzzz1a). Also, in the future, there's no need to delete one answer and post another, you can edit the other one.

Comment: Terser and simpler to code, true, but using a static assert as shown throws a nicer error message when it fails. Will keep the other advice in mind, thanks.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :) Nice solution.